# xsltTransformTimeout issue

Tags: xslt, sharepoint-2010, moss

I have a page designed using DataFormWebpart and this page retries data from a database using webservice.

This works fine in Moss 2007. But in sharepoint 2010, the page displays "Unable to display webpart".

This is an xsltTimeoutissue i guess. Because if i set the timeout value to 30, the page displays data. But setting the value to 30 may degrade the performance on the server.

Please suggest how i can resolve the issue - is it ok to set the xsltTransformTimeOut value 30? If not what is the way to resolve this?

Few more points about the page:
Page has lots of customisations - many if conditions , group by etc.
If the input date range is less (ex: difference between from and to date is 5 days) page works fine. Bur this is a report page and report should be for 1 month.

Thanks in advance
Usha

Comment: Sharepoint 2010 only supports XSLT 1.0, are you sure you don't use any XSLT 2.0 functions are something similar? Is your XSLT written correctly? Escaped all XML special characters? To increase the XSLT timeout, see: http://englando.wordpress.com/2012/01/05/unable-to-display-this-web-part-xsltlistview-and-xsltdataview-web-part-issues-in-ie/

Comment: Hi , thanks for your reply. The version used is 1.0, The xslt works when the date range (from and To dates) is small eg 5 days. Error happens only when date range is high

Comment: How do you group? Are you using keys? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxslt%5D%20muenchian%20grouping

Comment: I am new to xslt.... i will provide the maximum information i knew from the code.. There is a parameter binding dvt_groupfield and this value is used in if condition in many places in the xslt. I assume there is problem with this.

Comment: Best is to update your question and add an input XML and the XSLT you got.